# What is the value of the Dirichlet Eta Function at s=1/2?

Tags: number-theory

Although $\eta(1)$ is known to be $\ln(2)$, I have not seen an analytically calculated value for $\eta(\frac{1}{2});$

$$\eta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

A web calculator gives the value to be 0.6, which seems to be right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't just
$$\eta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}}{\sqrt{n}}=\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.6048986434$$

**Edit**

Remember the general relation
$$\eta\left(s\right)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right) \zeta (s)$$ If you want a quick and dirty shortcut evaluation, for $0 \leq s \leq 1$, you could use
$$\eta\left(s\right)=\frac 12+\left( \log (2)-\frac{1}{2}\right)\, s^{0.895}$$

Comment: Can you explain where the last equality comes from? I'm trying to solve a simpler problem, which asks to show that for that range of $s$ the sum of the series is always greater than $1/2$

Answer (score 7):

A careful computation shows that the numerical value is
$$0.6048986434216303702472...$$
which is not $0.6$. One should be aware that the above series converge really slowly.

As Claude Leibovici indicates, one can relate its value to the Riemann's Zeta function value at $1/2$. However, as far as I know, there is no analytic formula of $\zeta(1/2)$, so this is why you haven't seen an "analytically calculated value for $\eta(1/2)$".

EDIT2: As pointed again in the comments by leftaroundabout, I missread the OEIS link given in the answer of R. J. Mathar. What equals $$\gamma/2 + \pi/4 - (1/2 + \sqrt{2})\log(2) + \log(\pi)/2,$$where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, is $\eta'(1/2)/\eta(1/2)$ not $\eta(1/2)$.

Comment: You are very correct ! We start a no-end loop. By the way $\to +1$

Comment: It does seem to be expressible exactly in terms of the Euler-Mascheroni constant though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Do you have a reference, I searched, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Your formula (in EDIT) and the one at the OEIS link provided by Mathar do not match.

Comment: @user3059799 Corrected, editing from the phone is hard

Comment: Even though there is a constant in it, this formula is pretty sexy I reckon.

Comment: The formula seems incorrect - I get the wrong answer when calculating it. OEIS seems to say that if $c$ is the OP's constant, and $d$ is the constant described [here](http://oeis.org/A265162), then your formula gives $d/c$. The formula on OEIS for $d$ includes $\zeta(1/2)$, so I suspect all they are giving is Claude Leibovici's formula in disguise.

Comment: Yes Mike seems to be right. I got 0.319539205.

Answer (score 6):

The numerical value of 0.604898... is provided in http://oeis.org/A113024 .