# How do permutations of $\Bbb N$ affect series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, group-theory, convergence-divergence, permutations

Let $G$ be the group of all permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum a_n$ a conditionally convergent series of reals. What do we know about how $G$ "acts" on this series? We can partition $G$ according to how permutations $\pi$ affect the value $\sum_n a_{\pi n}$ or, more finely, the behavior of its partial sums. How much do we know about such partitions of $G$?

There should be some subgroup $H\subset G$ of permutations that do not affect the value of *any* conditionally convergent series. This includes all finite permutations, but it should also include any permutation $\pi$ for which $|\pi(i)-i|$ is bounded. Does $H$ include any more permutations than this, or is this all of $H$?

We can define $\Gamma_x\subset G$ as the set of $\pi$ for which $\sum a_{\pi n}=x$. If $\sum a_n=x$ then this is like a stabilizer, but I don't see any obvious reason to expect it to be a subgroup. Or, for general $x$, any reason to expect $\Gamma_x$ to act like a coset (e.g. the $\Gamma_x$s being translates of each other). Do these sets satisfy properties similar to cosets?

(One thing I can see is that each $\Gamma_x$ is a union of right cosets of $H$.)

Given a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ we can define $\Gamma_f$ as the set of those $\pi$ for which $\sum_{n\le N}a_{\pi n}\sim f(N)$. There are many variations we could use on this definition, and we could even use it for divergent series $\sum a_n$. Or, even if $S=\sum a_n$ is convergent, we could define $\Gamma_f$ (for $f\to 0$) according to $-S+\sum_{n\le N}a_{\pi n}\sim f(N)$ (so we partition $G$ according to how permutations affect the convergence of the series). I expect describing $\Gamma$s becomes much harder in these situations.

Do we know more answers to any of these questions for specific series, like harmonic or alternating harmonic?

Comment: Linking to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3037709) (asking a part of the above).