# Is every permutation of naturals that is convergent-invariant, a bounded permutation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Let $C$ be the set of sequences of real numbers whose associated series is convergent. I define a permutation $f$ of the naturals to be convergent-invariant if, for every sequence $a_n$ in $C$, the series of the sequence $a_{f(n)}$ converges, and to the same sum. Certainly, any permutation that moves only finitely many natural numbers is convergent-invariant. I was surprised to learn, however, that there are other convergent-invariant permutations. So, now, I define a bounded permutation to be a permutation that does not move natural numbers arbitrarily far. For example, the permutation that moves $0$ to $1$, $1$ to $0$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $2$, $4$ to $5$, $5$ to $4$, etc is bounded, because it does not move any natural number greater than a distance of $1$. So, my question now is, is being a bounded permutation equivalent to being a convergent-invariant permutation? If not, does either direction of the implication hold?

Comment: Related (self-plug): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946290/how-do-permutations-of-bbb-n-affect-series

Comment: [This old question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424390/rearrangement-conditional-convergence-and-placid-permutations) is also related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; while bounded permutations preserve convergence, convergence-preserving permutations need not be bounded.  For instance, consider the (unbounded) permutation that swaps $(1,2)$, $(4,8)$, $(16,32)$, etc., and leaves all other positions alone.  This permutation preserves convergence.  Proof: partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ up to $N=2-3,8-15,32-63,\ldots$ are unchanged, and any other partial sum is changed by $|a_x-a_y|$, where $x$ is the previous power of $2$ and $y$ is the next one.  By the assumption that $\sum_n a_n$ converges, this difference goes to zero as $N\rightarrow\infty$.  So the limit of the partial sums is the same after the permutation as it was before.

Comment: Call a permutation $\pi$ segmentable if it preserves a partition of $\Bbb N$ ("blockwise") into finite "runs" $\{1,\cdots,m\}$, $\{m+1,\cdots,n\}$, $\{n+1,\cdots\},\cdots$ and the supports of $\pi$'s restrictions are bounded. This argument applies to any segmentable permutation.

Comment: Those permutations are already included in the bounded permutations, no?  Or do you mean that only a bounded number of positions in each segment are not fixed?  In which case that’s right.  In fact the restriction to segments is not necessary, then.

Comment: The second interpretation, of course. I don't know what your first interpretation is. By "not necessary" do you mean there exist convergence-preserving permutations which are not segmentable, or do you mean the class of segmentable permutations can be redefined without reference to restricting to segments?

Comment: My first interpretation was that you were allowing *any* permutation of the elements in each segment.  Then I realized that "the supports of $\pi$'s restrictions are bounded" disallows that.  By "not necessary", I meant that you can redefine (and expand) the class, by allowing $\pi$ to be any product of disjoint permutations with bounded support.  But I'm not completely sure that works.

Comment: Define a "twist" on a linearly ordered set $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ to be $a_k\mapsto a_{n+1-k}$ (so basically a "reflection," but I'm using the word "twist" from braid theory). A twist is a product of disjoint transpositions. If we take the infinite product of twists from increasingly large (disjoint) segments, I suspect the result may not be convergence-preserving (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Being a bounded permutation preserves convergence and the sum, proved [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150964/prove-that-the-series-still-converges-under-a-permutation).

The converse is very interesting. The series invarianting and also the bounded permutations form subgroups. They just might be the same subgroup.